# How to stop text in tkinter from appearing blurry/pixelated in Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am using `tkinter` in python. Sharing the image [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/54xjq.png. The fonts I am using are:

```
font=("Ariel", 48, "italic")
font=("Ariel", 64, "italic")
```

Comment: Does your system have Ariel installed? If not, tkinter will automatically pick something else.

Comment: Ariel is a common font. It should be available.

Comment: Sure, it _should_. I’m asking if it _is_

Comment: It appear Ariel is not installed. i changed the font to Ubuntu. with that also, I am getting pixelated  Text.

Comment: You're getting bitmapped fonts rather than truetype fonts. Maybe your font server isn't running of you don't have any non-bitmapped fonts installed.

Comment: @BryanOakley How do i check if the font server is running or not? `fc-list | grep Ubuntu` shows fonts as truetype.